# SSL Error OmniAuth in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, omniauth

I've read a lot about this error especially in OmniAuth for Rails 3.  I have a few questions because currently I'm stuck on it.

The consensus in [this  post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat) was that it couldn't reference the certs properly.  My first question is this (I'm using Windows 7 to preface the question):

Where exactly in my hard drive would I begin to look to find the certs?  I used RailsInstaller to install Rails 3 and the only thing that I can find that is close to that location is in "Git" where there is a "cert" directory with the ca-path file.  However, the reference that most people have is this "/etc/certs/" or something (basically a relative url).  My question is where is the parent directory from which this is referenced?  It may be extremely simple but I just don't know.  Would it be my RailsInstaller folder in the C:/ directory?

Answer (score 1):

In my config\initializers\devise.rb

```
require "omniauth-facebook"

if RbConfig::CONFIG["host_os"] =~ /mingw|mswin/
    ca_file = File.expand_path Rails.root.join("config", "cacert.pem")

    ssl_options = {}
    ssl_options[:ca_path] = '/etc/ssl/certs' if Rails.env.staging?
    ssl_options[:ca_file] = ca_file

    config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET", # "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET" your got from facebook app registration
        :client_options => {:ssl => ssl_options}
else
    config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET"
end
```

file cacert.pem from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/ put to your rails app config directory

thanks to this posts:

- [Why does accessing a SSL site with Mechanize on Windows fail, but on Mac work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567973/why-does-accessing-a-ssl-site-with-mechanize-on-windows-fail-but-on-mac-work/8568915#8568915)
- http://grokbase.com/p/gg/rubyonrails-talk/121bfxzwke/rails-re-windows-rails-3-1-3-omniauth-browserid-ssl-erro

Answer (score 0):

Hi Vivek I resolve this issue on windows 7,
you can get certificate from here:
https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550

So location for this certificate will be **C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem**

Full image: config\initializers\omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, '4545454545fgdfg','545fg45fdh4f5d4gh5fd4h5fd4h5fd4h',
  {:scope => '', :client_options => { :ssl => { :ca_file => 'C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem'}}} 
end
```