# OpenSSL error from ruby script

Tags: ruby, windows, openssl

`SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`

This error is a pretty common one to anyone using ruby on windows.

For me, the solution has always been [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16134586/2287595).  It has worked great on any computer I have put it on and I've loved it.

Just this week it stopped working.  Has anyone else had this happen?

I've tried getting the cert from [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) again just in case the cert was no longer valid.  I tried removing and adding the environmental   I use mechanize and tried to reference it as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867930/open-ssl-errors-for-ruby-on-windows-7).

I've also tried going to different urls, "https://google.com" and others, for example.

Nothing so far.  Anyone have a better solution for this?  It has happened on all windows computers that I have this cert referenced this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be different to the one you linked to. There it failed to verify the certificate returned by the server. Here it erros earlier when it reads the server hello. Do you have any more debug information eg stacktrace or a pcap of the interaction?

A (highly) speculative explanation is that you sent an sslv2 compatible client hello and the server returned an ssl alert as it will only accept sslv3/tls format client hello